# Ways to cluster word senses with word embeddings

Tags: nlp, word-embeddings, word2vec, bert

I'm trying to ***semantically cluster polysemous words*** or word with different meanings in a corpus for my class study and I want to do it by *word embeddings* but I have no Idea how to reach to the clustered target that I want. (a similar target that I'm looking for is posted below as an image)

**What I have**: *a corpus*

**What I want**: *clustering of K frequent words with other most related semantically similar words in a corpus* considering that these words have multiple senses.

> For example: suppose word *cell* is repeated 5000 times in a corpus, here are some sentences:  "There are many organelles in a biological cell" , "He went to prison cell" and
> "we are running out of cell phones", in every sentence we are receiving *contextually a different meaning from cell*, respectively, *blood cell*, *prison* and *mobile/phone*.

So I want to cluster each word [for example *cell* in here] with their *semantically similar words*. (*sometime similar words are synonyms*)

**What I've done**:

- preprocessing corpus for finding K frequent words.
- As each meaning of word is contextualized to the correspondent sentence, I thought we could compare BERT vectors of those sentences with other sentences, but the problem is Bert compare vector to vector and different senses are dependent on their sentence but I don't know how I should correctly locate semantically similar words in sentences that are compared to the first sentence.

I searched for related papers, there was a *WordNet* that seems to be similar but it is not constructed with word embedding methods.

> Although there are word embeddings like `GloVe`, `FastText`, `Word2Vec` that can bring us similar words but the context would be ignored and I didn't find anywhere that they can work *semantically*!

And at last there was an `ELMo`, ELMo word representations take the entire input sentence into equation for calculating the word embeddings. Hence, the term *"cell"* would have different ELMo vectors under different contexts but it is still categorizing the words by their context and not putting Words that are semantically similar in a category, this way I have no Idea how to cluster different meanings by their semantically similar words.

Plus I've checked the papers and **WSD** is not the thing I want, maybe `Word Sense Induction` clustering` seems to be more accurate but still not exact.

Here is a photo of WordNet with word **Search**, kindda similar to the thing I want. (you can see each cluster of word *search* is connected semantically to their similar group)

[image: WordNet]

---

I'm asking here to get more ideas or maybe my intuitions are all wrong.

Thanks for your time.

Any information would be helpful and appreciated.

Comment: Did you already look into n-grams?